# Detect if a __getattribute__ call was due to hasattr

Tags: python, getattribute, hasattr

I'm re-implementing `__getattribute__` for a class.

I want to notice any incorrect (meaning failures are expected, of course) failures of providing attributes (because the `__getattribute__` implementation turned out quite complex). For that I log a warning if my code was unable to find/provide the attribute just before raising an `AttributeError`.

I'm aware:

1. `__getattribute__` implementations are encouraged to be as small as simple as possible.
2. It is considered wrong for a `__getattribute__` implementation to behave differently based on how/why it was called.
3. Code accessing the attribute can just as well `try/except` instead of using `hasattr`.

**TL;DR**: Nevertheless, I'd like to detect whether a call to `__getattribute__` was done due to `hasattr` (verses a "genuine" attempt at accessing the attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, even through stack inspection. `hasattr` produces no frame object in the Python call stack, as it is written in C, and trying to inspect the last Python frame to guess whether it's suspended in the middle of a `hasattr` call is prone to all kinds of false negatives and false positives.

If you're absolutely determined to make your best shot at it anyway, the most reliable (but still fragile) kludge I can think of is to monkey-patch `builtins.hasattr` with a Python function that *does* produce a Python stack frame:

```
import builtins
import inspect
import types

_builtin_hasattr = builtins.hasattr
if not isinstance(_builtin_hasattr, types.BuiltinFunctionType):
    raise Exception('hasattr already patched by someone else!')

def hasattr(obj, name):
    return _builtin_hasattr(obj, name)

builtins.hasattr = hasattr

def probably_called_from_hasattr():
    # Caller's caller's frame.
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    return frame.f_code is hasattr.__code__
```

Calling `probably_called_from_hasattr` inside `__getattribute__` will then test if your `__getattribute__` was probably called from `hasattr`. This avoids any need to assume that the calling code used the name "hasattr", or that use of the name "hasattr" corresponds to this particular `__getattribute__` call, or that the `hasattr` call originated inside Python-level code instead of C.

The primary sources of fragility here are if someone saved a reference to the real `hasattr` before the monkey-patch went through, or if someone else monkey-patches `hasattr` (such as if someone copy-pastes this code into another file in the same program). The `isinstance` check attempts to catch most cases of someone else monkey-patching `hasattr` before us, but it's not perfect.

Additionally, if `hasattr` on an object written in C triggers attribute access on your object, that will look like your `__getattribute__` was called from `hasattr`. This is the most likely way to get false positives; everything in the previous paragraph would give false negatives. You can protect against that by checking that the entry for `obj` in the `hasattr` frame's `f_locals` is the object it should be.

Finally, if your `__getattribute__` was called from a decorator-created wrapper, subclass `__getattribute__`, or something similar, that will not count as a call from `hasattr`, even if the wrapper or override was called from `hasattr`, even if you want it to count.

Comment: Thanks! overwriting `hasattr` is indeed a simple solution. I should have thought of that myself!

Answer (score -2):

You can use `sys._getframe` to get the caller frame and use `inspect.getframeinfo` to get the line of code that makes the call, and then use some sort of parsing mechanism such as regex (you can't use `ast.parse` since the one line of code is often an incomplete statement) to see if `hasattr` is the caller. It isn't very robust but it should work in most reasonable cases:

```
import inspect
import sys
import re
class A:
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if re.search(r'\bhasattr\b', inspect.getframeinfo(sys._getframe(1)).code_context[0]):
            print('called by hasattr')
        else:
            print('called by something else')
hasattr(A(), 'foo')
getattr(A(), 'foo')
```

This outputs:

```
called by hasattr
called by something else
```

Comment: This fails in plenty of reasonable cases, such as `if hasattr(thing, 'existing_attribute') and thing.existing_attribute == 5` or `if hasattr(different_thing, 'foo') or thing_with_getattribute.bar == 5`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've consider doing something similar but parsing the line is prone to errors. I hope to find something that is more error resistant, or at least has less false positives (I.e. I can accept missing `hasattr`-based calls but rather not miss "genuine" calls).

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, but if one actually needs the value of an attribute then he/she shouldn't use `hasattr` in the first place, but instead use `getattr` with a default value, or use a `try` block around `thing.existing_attribute`, to avoid a redundant and potentially dangerous (when there are multiple threads) call to `__getattribute__`. One should only use `hasattr` if all he/she cares about is the existence of the attribute but not the value of the attribute. If the coder follows this principle then the flaw with my method would not be an issue.

Comment: The very premise of this question is asking about how to do a thing that violates design principles. It seems unsafe to assume that the rest of the codebase stringently follows any particular principles. Also, `getattr` with a default is awkward when you need to be able to distinguish between attribute absence and an attribute value that happens to be the default, and this still fails even in cases where the rules you list are followed.