# Equality Comparison with NumPy Instance Invokes `__bool__`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, magic-methods

I have defined a class where its `__ge__` method returns an instance of itself, and whose `__bool__` method is not allowed to be invoked (similar to a Pandas `Series`).

**Why is `X.__bool__` invoked during `np.int8(0) <= x`, but not for any of the other examples?** Who is invoking it? I have read the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__) docs but I haven’t found my answer there.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class X:
    def __bool__(self):
        print(f"{self}.__bool__")
        assert False
    def __ge__(self, other):
        print(f"{self}.__ge__")
        return X()

x = X()

np.int8(0) <= x

# Console output:
# <__main__.X object at 0x000001BAC70D5C70>.__ge__
# <__main__.X object at 0x000001BAC70D5D90>.__bool__
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<stdin>", line 4, in __bool__
# AssertionError

0 <= x

# Console output:
# <__main__.X object at 0x000001BAC70D5C70>.__ge__
# <__main__.X object at 0x000001BAC70D5DF0>

x >= np.int8(0)

# Console output:
# <__main__.X object at 0x000001BAC70D5C70>.__ge__
# <__main__.X object at 0x000001BAC70D5D30>


pd_ge = pd.Series.__ge__
def ge_wrapper(self, other):
    print("pd.Series.__ge__")
    return pd_ge(self, other)

pd.Series.__ge__ = ge_wrapper

pd_bool = pd.Series.__bool__
def bool_wrapper(self):
    print("pd.Series.__bool__")
    return pd_bool(self)

pd.Series.__bool__ = bool_wrapper


np.int8(0) <= pd.Series([1,2,3])

# Console output:
# pd.Series.__ge__
# 0    True
# 1    True
# 2    True
# dtype: bool
```

Comment: I suspect it's because `False == 0`, so `np.int8(0)` is supposed to compare equal to boolean `False`.

Comment: But `False <= x` doesn't cause `X.__bool__` to be called.

Comment: It fails with `np.int8(1) <= x` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

`X.__array_priority__ = 1000`

---

The biggest hint is that it works with a `pd.Series`.

First I tried having `X` inherit from `pd.Series`. This worked (i.e. `__bool__`  no longer called).

To determine whether NumPy is using an `isinstance` check or duck-typing approach, I removed the explicit inheritance and added (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958013)):

```py
@property
def __class__(self):
    return pd.Series
```

The operation no longer worked (i.e. `__bool__` was called).

So now I think we can conclude NumPy is using a duck-typing approach. So I checked to see what attributes are being accessed on `X`.

I added the following to `X`:

```py
def __getattribute__(self, item):
    print("getattr", item)
    return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
```

Again instantiating `X` as `x`, and invoking `np.int8(0) <= x`, we get:

```
getattr __array_priority__
getattr __array_priority__
getattr __array_priority__
getattr __array_struct__
getattr __array_interface__
getattr __array__
getattr __array_prepare__
<__main__.X object at 0x000002022AB5DBE0>.__ge__
<__main__.X object at 0x000002021A73BE50>.__bool__
getattr __array_struct__
getattr __array_interface__
getattr __array__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 32, in <module>
    np.int8(0) <= x
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in __bool__
    assert False
AssertionError
```

Ah-ha! What is `__array_priority__`? Who cares, really. With a little digging, all we need to know is that `NDFrame` (from which `pd.Series` inherits) sets this value as `1000`.

If we add `X.__array_priority__ = 1000`, it works! `__bool__` is no longer called.

What made this so difficult (I believe) is that the NumPy code didn't show up in the call stack because it is written in C. I could investigate further if I tried out the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52940910).

Comment: I think we converged :) The attributes you traced, I think, are from the array produced from the original scalar in order to evaluate the rich comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `np.int8.__le__` is defined so that instead of returning `NotImplemented` and letting `X.__ge__` take over, it instead tries to return something like `not (np.int(8) > x)`, and *then* `np.int8.__gt__` raises `NotImplemented`. Once `X.__gt__(x, np.int8(0))` returns an instance of `X` rather than a Boolean value, then we need to call `x.__bool__()` in order to compute the value of `not x`.

(Still trying to track down where `int8.__gt__` is defined to confirm.)

(Update: not quite. `int8` uses a single generic rich comparison function that simply converts the value to a 0-dimensional array, then returns the result of `PyObject_RichCompare` on the array and `x`.)

---

I did find [this function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/623bc1fae1d47df24e7f1e29321d0c0ba2771ce0/numpy/core/src/umath/_rational_tests.c.src#L313) that appears to ultimately implement `np.int8.__le__`:

```
static NPY_INLINE int
rational_le(rational x, rational y) {
    return !rational_lt(y,x);
}
```

It's not clear to me how we avoid getting to this function if one of the arguments (like `X`) would not be a NumPy type. I think I give up.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this for me. It was quite a headache to debug, and I gather you felt the same :)